# Does a magnetic field rotate around itself as charge moves through a conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism

In all "right hand rule" images there are always tiny arrows around the magnetic field, pointing to it direction,but what is this direction?
Does a magnetic field rotate around itself ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The circle with an arrow is an easier way of indicating a vector field where all the arrows point in a circular direction around the wire. This would be a more accurate representation of the field, with the wire coming out of the screen:

[image: Rotational vector field]

The direction of the magnetic field is tangent to the circles in the drawing you showed. The field is static as long as the current is constant.

Comment: But what does this direction mean ? does it rotate counter clockwise ? and if the current moves in the opposite direction would the magnetic field then rotate clockwise ? it all seems so different from  the way a magnetic field is usually represented in drawings with a S and N poles and lines coming out from one pole to the other.